# Excel Pivot Table into Specific Format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bit of a weird situation and im currently using a pivot table to get my info in excel then manually format it to what it needs to look like for the end users.

**This is my pivot table**
[image: This is my pivot table]

**Here is the hierarchy for how the data needs to be displayed**
[image: Here is the hierarchy for how the data needs to be displayed]

**Example of an End Product**
[image: Example of an End Product]

I am wondering if there could be an easier way to do it instead of manually feeding those cells.

Comment: Do you have a brief sample of data to use? And where do you get the contact info? Is that in the data used to build the pivot, or rather, is it found elsewhere?

Comment: Are you looking for Classic layout for PivotTable?

Comment: Consider that "*using a pivot table to get my info in excel*" may not be ideal given your desired output.  Might be easier to start with the raw data and convert that. Power Query is one built-in tool that might be able to more easily handle that transformation.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what I would call an "unwrapping" of row data. Say you have column headers A B C D, with row data like this:

```
A B C D
w x y z
f g h i
```

And you want to unwrap it like this:

```
A w
B x
C y
D z

A f
B g
C h
D i
```

You can use this formula in a new sheet (assuming sheet1 contains the data, starting with headers in row 1 and data from row 2). In A1:A10000

```
=INDEX(SHEET1!$A$1:$D$1, MOD(ROW()-1, 4)+1)
```

And in B1:B10000

```
=INDEX(SHEET1!$A$2:$D$2501, INT((ROW()-1)/4)+1, MOD(ROW()-1, 4)+1)
```

With a bit of tweak, you could even include a blank "" row as a spacer.

Also, FYI, you might be able to do this unwrapping with power query (old excel) or "Get and Transform" (renamed in Excel 365). It sounds more daunting than it is, but have a youtube search for some guides.